# Please help me understand this C++ parameter declaration with an argument

Tags: c++, syntax, arguments, function-declaration

I use the ROOT C++ libraries (root.cern.ch) daily and was browsing the source when I came across this function declaration:

```
TString TString::Format(const char *va_(fmt), ...)
{
    //etc.
```

It can be found [here](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/src/TString.cxx.html#2329).

I don't understand how a `const char *` can have an argument or a parenthesis in its name.
The expression `va_(fmt)` is later used as a simple `const char *` even though it looks like a function call or a constructor. At first I thought it had something to do with the variable argument list, which was also new to me, but reading documentation on stdarg.h didn't help with this question at all.

It is very hard to google for help since I'm not really sure what to call this. A declaration with an argument? That doesn't give any good results.

I used to think I knew C++, but what is going on here? All help will be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that `va_` is simply a macro. Probably one that does nothing but expand to its parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a macro - in `Varargs.h`:

```
#if ...
#  define va_(arg) __builtin_va_alist
#else
#  define va_(arg) arg
#endif
```

Comment: We tell C programmers that `#define` just obfuscates, but do they believe us? *No...* ^_-

Comment: Another example of why macros are bad. If `fmt` were a type then the syntax would be a valid declaration of a function taking, as an argument named `va_`, a pointer to a function returning `char const *`.

Comment: How does this even make any difference in the function in question, compared to just naming the parameter `va_fmt`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Joe leaves out the clause on the `#if`. It's probably something like `#if SOME_FANCY_OPTIMIZED_STDARG_COMPILER_OPTION_ENABLED`. What this code does is give you `TString TString::Format(const char *__builtin_va_alist, ...)` if the fancy compiler option is enabled, or `TString TString::Format(const char *fmt, ...)` if not. There's no `va_fmt` anywhere.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: yeah I know. The thing is, inside the function the parameter is only ever called through the macro, there's no plain `__builtin_va_list` or `fmt`. So regardless of what the macro expands to, that name will turn up, shadow any variable with the same name outside the function, and lead to exactly the same behaviour regardless what the name is. That's what I think, but obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: What you're missing is that the compiler treats `__builtin_va_list` specially, and not as a straight forward parameter name. Generally, anything starting with a double underscore is compiler secret sauce.